# Will an H1B visa refusal under section 212 (a)(6)(E) cause problems for a Canada visa application?

Tags: canada, h1b-visas, visa-rejections

My US H1B visa application was rejected under  section 212 (a)(6)(E), even though I am validly married in my country.  Now I am applying for a visa to Canada.  Will this create any problems for me?

I am talking to a lawyer about a waiver of the section 212 (a)(6)(E) rejection.

Comment: What type of Canadian visa are you applying for?  If it's a work or study visa, then http://expatriates.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask.

Comment: @Sitin What advice has your lawyer given?

Comment: As a result, did you incur a permanent bar from the US? If so, yes, it's may affect a visa application to Canada.

Comment: I assume that you were accused of a 'sham marriage'. Be aware that having a valid marriage in any country does not mean that a marriage cannot be found to be 'sham'. A 'sham' marriage is one conducted for the purpose of enabling one of the parties to immigrate, and even valid marriages can come under that definition.

Comment: 6C or 6E? (6)(E) is for "smuggling" an alien (including bringing a child across the border illegally). That doesn't sound like your description. Inadmissibility for fraud or misrepresentation would be (6)(C)(i)

Comment: @user102008 6(e) can be applied in a wide variety of cases where fraud or misrepresentation was used to bring someone else into the country.

Comment: @user102008 [Section 212(a)(6)(E) Alien Smuggling](https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/AFM/HTML/AFM/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-17138/0-0-0-17444.html) In the Diversity Lottery, marriages concluded after notification of being selected trigger scrutiny of a sham marriage, e.g., a person who wants to immigrate but doesn't win the Lottery pays a Lottery winner to get married so that s/he is eligible to immigrate as the spouse. If the consular officer considers the marriage a sham, the Lottery winner is permanently barred as an *alien smuggler* and the other “spouse” barred for committing fraud.

Answer (score 2):

> Will an H1B visa refusal under section 212 (a)(6)(E) cause problems for a Canada visa application?

Potentially, yes, as inadmissability under § 212(a)(6)(E) puts in place a permanent bar and the [United States and Canada do share immigration information](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/news/archives/backgrounders-2012/immigration-information-sharing-treaty.html):

> The adoption of the Immigration Information Sharing Treaty enables our two countries to share systematically information from third-country nationals who apply for a visa or permit to travel to either country.
>
> When a third-country national applies to Canada for a visa or a permit, or claims asylum, Canada will send an automated request for data to the United States. The request will contain limited information, such as name and date of birth in the case of biographic sharing, or an anonymous fingerprint in the case of biometric sharing. If the identity matches that on a previous application, immigration information may be shared, such as whether the person has previously been refused a visa or removed from the other country.